# Is there a closed-form formula for the derivative of the orthogonal polar factor of a matrix?

Tags: soft-question, closed-form, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

$\newcommand{\psym}{\text{Psym}_n}$
$\newcommand{\sym}{\text{sym}}$
$\newcommand{\Sym}{\operatorname{Sym}}$
$\newcommand{\Skew}{\operatorname{Skew}}$
$\newcommand{\SO}{\operatorname{SO}_n}$
$\renewcommand{\skew}{\operatorname{skew}}$
$\newcommand{\GLp}{\operatorname{GL}_n^+}$

Let $\psym$ be the space of real symmetric positive-definite $n \times n$ matrices, and $\GLp$ be the group of real $n \times n$ invertible matrices with positive determinant.

Let $O:\GLp \to \SO$ be the orthogonal polar factor map, defined by requiring $A=
O(A)P$ for some symmetric positive-definite $P$. Note that $O(A)=A(\sqrt{A^TA})^{-1}$.

> Is there a nice "closed-form **algebraic formula**" for the differential $dO_A$? If not, perhaps there is a formula for  $\langle dO_A(B),C \rangle $? (similarly to what happens with the Levi-Civita connection, where we have an implicit characterization of $\nabla_XY$ in terms of the [Koszul formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry#The_Koszul_formula)).

**I am fine with using positive matrix square roots and inverses**, but not with using integral formulas or vectorization operations [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541052/104576) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1320527/104576). (I also don't want to use explicitly the singular values of $A$).

*Here are some partial results:*

1. Since $dO_{QA}(QB)=QdO_A(B)$ (and $dO_{AQ}(BQ)=dO_A(B)Q$), the question can be reduced to the case where $A \in \psym$. (The "dual" orthogonal case is easy: $dO_{Id}(B)=\skew(B)$, and for every $Q \in \SO$, $dO_{Q}(QB)=Q\skew B$).
2. For every $B \in \skew, dO_A(OBP)=OB$, i.e. $dO_A(X)=XP^{-1}$ if $O^TXP^{-1} \in \skew$: Set $\alpha(t)=Oe^{tB}P$. Then $O(\alpha(t))=Oe^{tB}$, so $dO_A(OBP)=OB$.

The problem with calculating $dO_A(OBP)$ when $B \in \sym$, is that $e^{tB}P$ does not need to be symmetric, even though $e^{tB},P$ are both positive-definite. If this was the case, then it would imply $dO_A(OBP)=O\skew B$, which is false in general (see below).

---

One could conjecture that perhaps $dO_A(OBP)=OB$ holds also for $B \in \sym$, or equivalently that $dO_A(X)=XP^{-1}$ for every $X \in M_n$. This is false since $dO_A$ is not injective, due to dimensional incompatibility.

> Another possible conjecture is $dO_A(OBP)=O\skew B$. However, this is also false:

Indeed, for $A=P \in \psym$, this reduces to $dO_P(BP)=\skew B$. Suppose that $C:=BP \in \sym$. Then must have $dO_P(BP)=0$. Indeed, by differentiating $A=OP$ we obtain
$$ \dot A=\dot O P+O\dot P, \tag{1}$$

which for $A=P,O=Id$ becomes $ \dot A=\dot O P+\dot P$. Note that $C \in \sym \Rightarrow dP_P(C)=C$ (since $P_{\psym}=Id_{\psym}$ and $C \in T_P{\psym}$), i.e. $\dot P=\dot A$, which implies $\dot O=0$.

*Thus, we proved that $BP \in \sym$ implies $dO_P(BP)=0$.* However, this is incompatible with $dO_P(BP)=\skew B$ in general: $BP \in \sym \iff BP=PB^T$.

For $P=\text{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2), B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\\ c & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, this happens if and only if $\sigma_2b=\sigma_1c$, so if $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$, then $B$ is not symmetric. Thus, $dO_P(BP)=0 \neq \skew B$.

---

*Comment:* Equation $(1)$ implies that one can equivalently focus upon the "dual" problem, of computing $dP_A$, instead of $dO_A$. Here is a previous attempt of mine to [go in this direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047462/is-there-a-closed-form-formula-for-the-derivative-of-the-positive-factor-of-a-ma).

Answer (score 2):

Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
 F &= A(A^TA)^{-1/2} \cr
 Q &= I-AA^+ = \,Q^T \cr
 V^T &= A^+ \cr
}$$
where $A^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse.

Then
$$\eqalign{
 FF^T &= A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T \cr&= AA^+ \cr
d(FF^T) &= d(AA^+) \cr
dF\,F^T+F\,dF^T  &= Q\,dA\,A^+ + V\,dA^T\,Q \cr
}$$
At this point, you have stressed that you don't want to use vectorization, so let's try solving it using 4th order tensors.

There are 3 isotropic tensors $({\mathcal H},{\mathcal J},{\mathcal K})$ and their components can be expressed in terms of Kronecker symbols.
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal H}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl} \cr
{\mathcal J}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ij}\,\delta_{kl} \cr
{\mathcal K}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{il}\,\delta_{jk} \cr
}$$
We can use these to rearrange that last differential
$$\eqalign{
({\mathcal H}F + F{\mathcal K}):dF
 &= (Q{\mathcal H}V + V{\mathcal H}Q:{\mathcal K}):dA \cr
}$$
Now we need to calculate a 4th order tensor ${\mathcal P}$ which is the inverse (under the double-contraction product) of the tensor on the LHS, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal H}&= {\mathcal P}:\big({\mathcal H}F + F{\mathcal K}\big)\cr
}$$
This allow us to isolate $dF$ and calculate the gradient as
$$\eqalign{
dF
 &= \Big({\mathcal P}:(Q{\mathcal H}V + V{\mathcal H}Q:{\mathcal K})\Big):dA \cr
\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}
 &= {\mathcal P}:(Q{\mathcal H}V + V{\mathcal H}Q:{\mathcal K}) \cr
}$$
In the above, juxtaposition indicates a single-contraction product, while a colon represents double-contraction. Here are some examples in component form
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal A} &= {\mathcal B}:{\mathcal C} &\implies
{\mathcal A}_{ijmn} &= \sum_{kl}{\mathcal B}_{ijkl}\,{\mathcal C}_{klmn}
\cr
{\alpha} &= {B}:{C} &\implies
{\alpha} &= \sum_{ij}{B}_{ij}\,{C}_{ij}
\cr
{A} &= BC &\implies
{A}_{ik} &= \sum_{j}{B}_{ij}\,{C}_{jk}
\cr
{\mathcal A} &= B\,{\mathcal C} &\implies
{\mathcal A}_{iklm} &= \sum_{j}{B}_{ij}\,{\mathcal C}_{jklm}
\cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I understand some things: As I defined it, the matrix $A$ is invertible, and so $A^+=A^{-1}$. (In particular $Q=0$ ). Also, $FF^T=Id$, since $F$ is orthogonal; Do you gain anything from writing $FF^T=AA^+$?

Comment: Also, differentiating $d(FF^T) = d(AA^+) $ should result in $dF\,F^T+F\,dF^T  =dA\,A^+ + A\,dA^{+}$, while you wrote
$dF\,F^T+F\,dF^T  = Q\,dA\,A^+ + V\,dA^T\,Q $...

Comment: If $A^+=A^{-1}$ then $Q=0$. In which case you need to find the tensor equivalent of the nullspace projector to solve the problem. Let ${\mathcal M}=({\mathcal H}F+F{\mathcal K})$ and let's re-purpose ${\mathcal P}$ to be the **pseudoinverse** rather than the regular inverse. So the gradient is $$\eqalign{{\mathcal M}:{\mathcal P}:{\mathcal M}&={\mathcal M}\quad&({\rm defines\,pseudoinverse})\cr {\mathcal M}:dF &= 0\quad&({\rm dF\,lies\,in\,the\,nullspace})\cr dF &= ({\mathcal H}-{\mathcal P}:{\mathcal M}):dA \cr \frac{\partial F}{\partial A} &= ({\mathcal H}-{\mathcal P}:{\mathcal M}) \cr }$$